# Can I set the cwd of a call to the Babel CLI?

Tags: babeljs

I'm running the command:

```
babel -x jsx -d app/built/ app/emails/*.jsx
```

It's transpiling `app/emails/*.jsx` to `app/built/app/emails/*.js`

Does Babel have a parameter that would directly transpile to `app/built/*.js`? i.e. to trim the `app/emails/` part of the output file?

For my use case, flattening would be acceptable, but really, the trim would be most useful (so that hierarchy below `app/emails` is maintained.

Comment: Why not `cd app/emails` first?

Comment: I'm trying to determine whether or not I need to.

Answer (score 1):

There is not an option for this. The filepath is just joined with the output folder. The best way to do this would be

```
cd app/emails && babel -x jsx -d ../built *.jsx
```